# Python DCM API file download location

Tags: python, download, double-click-advertising, google-python-api

I am using [this DCM Python example scrip](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/blob/master/python/v3_0/download_file.py) to download files from DCM. It is working well however it downloads the file to location of the scrip. How would I go about specifying a location on my pc for it to download to? Sorry i am a little new to python. Tried reading the documentation but no mention  of it. Any help would be amazing.

I thought it would have to be to do with editing line 75 (below), however that is in the print statement so doesn't really change anything.

```
print('File %s downloaded to %s'
        % (report_file['id'], os.path.realpath(out_file.name)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out, just had to add the path to report file function.